# Postgresql - error returned more than one row from function

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic, sql-function, generated-columns

My first post in Stackoverflow.  I am trying to learn Postgresql (12) "on the job" and seem to be stuck on a rather simple issue.  I have a simple database with 12 rows. In one column (int) there is a 4-digit number [representing a year].  I am trying to create a generated always column that takes the Current Date, subtract the previously mentioned int column to get an Age (int).

What am I missing. There is surely a simple solution.

Thanks
James

After several failed attempts, I realize that a function should work.  Here is the simple Function I created. The function works but seems to be returning more than 1 row.  I just need the Asset_Age generated always column to show the age of the asset:  [inservice is the existing int column that has the 4 digit (ex. 1963)]

```
--Function get_age

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION amp.get_age()
RETURNS int
AS $CODE$
BEGIN
    RETURN extract (year from current_date)::int - inservice from amp.amp_pumpstations;
    
End
$CODE$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE.

--------------

--create generated always column
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS amp.amp_pumpstations
    ADD COLUMN asset_age integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((amp.get_age())) STORED;
    
-------------

ERROR:  query "SELECT extract(year from current_date)::int - inservice from amp.amp_pumpstations" returned more than one row
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function amp.get_age() line 3 at RETURN
SQL state: 21000
```

Comment: `- inservice from amp.amp_pumpstations` which row from the table? I'm guessing you have some idea of "current row" but that doesn't mean anything in the function. Try writing a function that takes `inservice` and does a simple calculation. That could be a plain SQL function too.

Answer (score 2):

`CURRENT_DATE` being a [`STABLE` function (value remains constant in a single statement), you should not use that in an `IMMUTABLE` function (function result is always the same for the same function arguments)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html). It may "work" today but next year you likely have a problem because the function may have been "optimised". By extension, you cannot use a `GENERATED ALWAYS` column because that needs an `IMMUTABLE` function.

On top of that, the logic is faulty in that the `asset_age` [is calculated when the row is inserted in the table or its underlying columns updated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) so as time moves on your asset ages go out of sync.

You can most easily solve your issue by dropping column `asset_age` from your table and create a view that calculates the value whenever you need it:

```
CREATE VIEW amp.amp_pumpstations_age AS
    SELECT *, extract(year from current_date) - inservice AS asset_age
    FROM amp.amp_pumpstations;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_age()
RETURNS SETOF integer
AS $CODE$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select extract (year from current_date)::int - inservice 
    from amp_pumpstations;
    
End
$CODE$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL IMMUTABLE
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nUxqqfH0)

Comment: This may "work" but it is incorrect, because `CURRENT_DATE` is not `IMMUTABLE`. As soon as next year rolls around you may have an "optimised" function that gives wrong results.